# How to create a memorymapped view of my file that shows only select rows by line starting constant

Tags: c#, .net

So, I am working with really large data files and am want to memory map the file and then create a view to represent the parts of the file that I need at the particular instance. Anyone have an example that maps just rows in a file that start with a particular letter, constant, etc? I would like to, in the example below, have a view map rows where the line start with "ORD" these are product order detail rows, while lines that start with the constant "ITM" are product order item rows.  Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
   if (File.Exists(loadFile))
            {
                // Create the memory-mapped representation of the file. 
                using (var mmapLoadFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(loadFile, FileMode.Open, "ProductOrderMap"))
                {

                }

  // Create the memory-mapped representation of the file. 
                using (var mmapLoadFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(loadFile, FileMode.Open, "ProductOrderItemsMap"))
                {

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic: if you need to start reading data from a specific string, you just have to firstly search that string. I mean, you have to read the file from the very beginning and look for the bytes, which represent your string "\r\nORD" in a proper encoding.

Comment: So, I don't get the luxury of being able to parse the file records using Linq or some other dynamic expression language?